# Returning a subset of a dataframe using a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to python so I apologize in advance if this is a rookie mistake. I'm using python 3.4. Here's the problem:

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetimeindex and multiple named columns like so:

```
>>>df
                         'a'                 'b'                'c'    
1949-01-08             42.915                  0            1.448   
1949-01-09             19.395                  0            0.062   
1949-01-10              1.077               0.05            0.000   
1949-01-11              0.000              0.038            0.000   
1949-01-12              0.012              0.194            0.000   
1949-01-13              0.000                  0            0.125   
1949-01-14              0.000              0.157            0.007   
1949-01-15              0.000              0.003            0.000
```

I am trying to extract a subset using both the year from the datetimeindex and a conditional statement on the values:

```
>>>df['1949':'1980'][df > 0]
                         'a'                 'b'                'c'   
1949-01-08             42.915                NaN            1.448   
1949-01-09             19.395                NaN            0.062   
1949-01-10              1.077               0.05              NaN   
1949-01-11                NaN              0.038              NaN   
1949-01-12              0.012              0.194              NaN   
1949-01-13                NaN                NaN            0.125   
1949-01-14                NaN              0.157            0.007   
1949-01-15                NaN              0.003              NaN
```

My final goal is to find percentiles of this subset, however np.percentile cannot handle NaNs. I have tried using the dataframe quantile method but there are a couple of missing data points which cause it to drop the whole column. It seems like it would be simple to use a conditional statement to select values without returning NaNs, but I can't seem to find anything that will return a smaller subset without the NaNs. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly result you expect.

You can use `df >= 0` to  keep `0` in columns.

```
df['1949':'1980'][df >= 0]
```

You can use `.fillna(0)` to change `NaN` into `0`

```
df['1949':'1980'][df > 0].fillna(0)
```

You can use `.dropna()` to remove rows with any `NaN` - but this way probably you get empty result.

```
df['1949':'1980'][df > 0].dropna()
```